# Adding a collection of different object to an ArrayBuffer

Tags: scala

I wanted to add different objects to an ArrayBuffer collection, so I have to define  a base class

```
case class base (a:String,b:String)
case class Super1 (a:String, b:String, c:String) extends base(a,b)
case class Super2 (a:String, b:String, c:String, d:String) extends base(a,b)
val array=New ArrayBuffer[base]()
val super1=new Super1("1","2","super1")
val super2=new Super2("1","2","super2","super2")
array+=(super1)
array+=(super2)
```

Actually, have not tested the above code but want to know if the adding object are Super1 or Super2 instead of the base class as I need the value of all parameters in the derived classes..

Answer (score 1):

Your first problem is that you can't inherit from a `case class`.  Use a straight `class` or `trait` and you're OK.

After the class instances have been loaded into, and then extracted from, the `ArrayBuffer`, you can use pattern matching to determine the correct type.

```
array+=super1
array+=super2
array.head match {
  case Super1(a,b,c) => println("got 1")
  case Super2(a,b,c,d) => println("got 2")
  case _ => println("got bad")
}
```

There are a few other problems with your "not tested" code, but they're easily addressed.

Comment: Hi, If I add a trait to base class such as extends Ordered [base] { def compare (that: base) = {
        if (this.length == that.length)
            0
        else if (this.length> that.length)
            1
        else
            −1
    }}..do I need to implement them on child classes?

Comment: @user2021147; 1st -- It's not proper to ask a new question in the comments section of a previous question because A) fewer people will see it and offer answers, and B) whoever answers the new question can't get any up-votes and reputation points. 2nd -- This question is easily answered just by dropping a few lines of code into a REPL or IDE.  3rd -- No. After the base is `Ordered` then all the child classes are as well. No `override` is needed unless you want to change the `Ordered` rules.